# PhpStorm doesn't see new font

Tags: fonts, phpstorm

I want to use Monaco font in PhpStorm 8.0. I installed this font using [this](https://gist.github.com/rogerleite/99819) script. According to fc-list installation was successful:

```
$ fc-list | grep monaco
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-monaco/Monaco_Linux.ttf: Monaco:style=Regular
```

But PhpStorm still doesn't display it in available fonts. I've unchecked "Show only monospaced fonts" but there is no Monaco in list. I've tried invalidating cache and restarting PhpStorm but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you restarted PhpStorm since then? The list of fonts is loaded only once per session.

Comment: @LazyOne, as I said, I've tried both restarting and invalidating cache, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Same problem, very frustrating... let me know if you figured it out please!

Comment: This problem is still present in 2017. This is totally absurd.

Comment: Try putting the font inside Your home directory `.fonts` and run `fc-cache -fv` , then restart `phpstorm` and check list of fonts.

Comment: Be sure to validate the fonts after installation.

Comment: Problem _still_ exists, and it's corona year